# Shortening an URL and Sharing it on Twitter with a Keyboard Shortcut on Firefox/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, twitter, url-shortening

Say I am on a given website, I would like to, with a keyboard shortcut, shorten the link (e.g. using BitLy or some other URL shortening service), and then have a small dialog window open where I can add text to my tweet, before I finally share it by pressing enter.

I remember Google Reader had a bookmarklet that did this precisely. The bookmarklet was just an "URL" that had Javascript code to grab the current URL (the one to share), and then it would open a dialog window where I could use to enter additional text before sharing. I could then associate this "URL" with a keyboard shortcut on Firefox, and voila, I could quickly share things on Google Reader from a keyboard shortcuts.

Are there any bookmarklets for quickly shortening and sharing URLs on Twitter?